# How to debug 3DSecureStatus

Tags: opayo, 3d-secure

I am busy with implementing payments using Sage Pay direct protocol 3.0
(4,0 unavailable yet as I understand)

1. I register transaction using vspdirect-register.vsp
2. I redirect user to ACSURL with MD, PAReq and TermUrl using POST
3. I catch user on TermUrl and check transaction status using direct3dcallback.vsp with MD and PARes

BUT on this stage I always get:

- STATUS: 'OK'
- AVSCV2: 'ALL MATCH',
- StatusDetail: '0000 : The Authorisation was Successful.',
- AddressResult: 'MATCHED',
- PostCodeResult: 'MATCHED',
- CV2Result: 'MATCHED',
- '3DSecureStatus': 'ERROR'

Using MySagePay tools I get an explanation like :

> 3D secure status  The authentication callback message was MALFORMED. No 3D-Authentication occurred! ERROR
>   Attempt 1
>   ECI result Unknown result type

How can I debug this error?

Is it normal that I get status OK even when 3DSecureStatus : ERROR ?

Answer (score 1):

## Q1: Why are you getting a 3-D Secure error?

The `MALFORMED` status points towards SagePay not being able to read your request .. (e.g it's syntactically or structurally invalid etc).

Given the lack of code in the OP, rather than try and guess what you're doing wrong, I'll instead show what we do (which works - we've implemented both v3.00 & 4.00).

We perform an HTTP POST with the following parameters to `https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/direct3dcallback.vsp` (or `https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/direct3dcallback.vsp` in the case of testing):

### For direct protocol v3.00

- VPSProtocol: "3.00"
- MD: *MD posted to `TermURL`* (e.g 20156570522002324295)
- PARes: *"PARes posted to `TermURL`"*

### For direct protocol v4.00

- VPSProtocol: "4.00"
- VPSTxId: *VPSTxId from the initial payment response* (**Note that curly brackets `{}` need to be removed!!!**)
- CRes: *"CRes that was posted to the `ThreeDSNotificationURL`"*

## Q2: Why do you get an OK status when 3-D Secure failed?

I believe this is probably due to your merchant ruleset. You can state what you want to happen with the transaction if 3-D Secure is unavailable or fails.

So, check your ruleset. I believe that we force our consumers through 3-D Secure as our chargeback percentages were quite high otherwise.

## Footnote

I would also concur that since you are doing this work, it would probably be more beneficial to implement version 4.00, since that means the majority of your customers should have a better experience, and you'll have a better conversion rate too. Win win.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for advise! Currently we implementing both of them. One of our targets is - add 3dsecure soon as possible so we decide to release 3.0 firstly because 4.0 still in development.
Related to `MALFORMED` status - yeah meaning is clear but i can't understand on which stage we can send invalid request, `vspdirect-register.vsp` response have status `3DAUTH` , response from `direct3dcallback.vsp` also `OK `.

Comment: If i get it right - to fix issue with successful transaction when 3DSecure failed we should apply rule `Perform the 3D secure authentication` for price range like `0.1 - 1000` for example

Answer (score 0):

Protocal 4.0 is available on the SagePay test server and you can start working on that already. It needs to be implemented by the 14th of September 2019 and the last info I've got from SagePay support staff is that the protocal 4.0 will be on the live server by the 14th of September 2019.

To your probelm: I call the ACSURL with the added query string for MD, PaReq, TermUrl which works ok.
I see that you posted PAReq. Please note that I use PaReq. A small a instead of a capital A. See page 16 of the Documentation. [DIRECT_Integration_and_Protocol_4_Guidelines.pdf](https://www.sagepay.co.uk/library/document/directintegrationandprotocol4guidelinespdf)

Maybe you could post the complete URL you post to SagePay.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, we implement it also, but currently we want to release 3DSecure before 14th of September 2019.
btw: https://www.fca.org.uk/news/press-releases/fca-agrees-plan-phased-implementation-strong-customer-authentication , it also can affect on release date of new protocol

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!
Sage support have helped me to find issue.
The point was - route 'ThreeDSNotificationURL' make changes in 'CRes' as we have configured some security behaviors, and when we check this key on Sage side - we got an error. so some extra security behaviors for this route have solve the issue.

Thanks guys!